# Two validation groups

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms, validation

I have the following form:
part one:
a form that you have to fill anyway
part two:
a checkbox 
if you check the checkbox you will see part two form
if you dont check the checkbox ,part two form would be hidden

at the end of this page you have a send button.

the problem is: whenever i do not check the checkbox and the second form is hidden it doesnt send nothing because the button and the two forms have the same validation groups and of course when form two is hidden nobody fill the fields and i should cancle somehow the validation of them (to stay only with the validation of the first form that you should fill anyway-with or without checkbox).

what is the best solution/s?

thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in best practices with *ASP.NET* so here's some general advice
You can do a check if the checkbox is checked or not and only validate the second form if it's checked. Sample pseudocode below:

```
Validate(form1, form2, checkbox)
  bool1 = validate(form1)
  if(checkbox.checked)
    bool2 = validate(form2)
    return bool1 && bool2
  else
    return bool1
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, lets have two validation groups.One for fields in Form1 and another for fields in Form2.For eg : valform1 and valform2.

```
   <asp:Button ID="yourButton" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonSave_Click"
   CausesValidation="false" TabIndex="6"
   OnClientClick="return (Page_ClientValidate('valform1') && Page_ClientValidate('valform2'));" />
```

See if that works.